# Can't call object properly with promises

Tags: javascript, node.js

My code was working fine until I decided I wanted to try and return two values in my promise chain to the next function. I can call one of the values but not the other.

My code looks like this

```
app.get('/projects', (req, res) => {
practice.screamIt('matt').then((name) => {
    return [practice.translateIt(name), name]; //puts name as the parameter for next function
}).then((translate) => {
    console.log(translate[1] + ' test occured here')
    console.log(translate[0][0].englishName)
    return [`The name you entered is ${translate[1]}`, `${translate[0].englishName} is ${translate[0].spanishName} in spanish`]
}).then((value)=>{

    res.render('projects', {
    pageTitle: "Projects Page",
    practice: practice,
    value1: value[0],
    value2: value[1]
});

}).catch((errorMessage)=>{
    console.log(errorMessage)
})

});
```

And when I log the first bit of data it shows:

```
[ Promise { { englishName: 'Matt', spanishName: 'Mateo' } },'Matt' ]
```

I want to be able to call englishName, but can't seem to do so without getting undefined. I need to be able to call englishName in order for my second function work as intended.

Comment: is practice.translateIt(name) a promise?  It looks like you're returning a promise in an array which won't work properly with the then I believe.  I may be mistaken about that but I'm pretty sure that won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first resolve the `translateIt()` promise and use another `then()` to create the array

Change:

```
return [practice.translateIt(name), name];
```

To

```
return practice.translateIt(name).then(translate => [translate, name]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a full copy if your code but it appears you're returning a Promise in an Array to the then handler which I don't believe will work?

```js
practice.screamIt('matt').then((name) => {
    return practice.translateIt(name);
}).then((translate) => {
    ...etc
}).catch((errorMessage)=>{
    console.log(errorMessage)
});
```

If you try something like that I believe that would work for you as it would be returning the result once the promise resolves.

Comment: Yes it's what I was doing before. I was trying to return the name parameter with the promise as two separate values just to test some strings. I beleive i got it to work by using return practice.translateIt(name) && name; Let me run it and ill confirm

Comment: Ah I see what you were going for - yeah the guy above has a better answer than mine.  Haven't had my coffee yet :)

Comment: I appreciate anyone who takes the time to help a brother out. Especially a noob like me. So thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to return `Promise.all([practice.translateIt(name), name])` instead of `practice.translateIt(name)` as I its returning a promise.

That should return a single promise resolving to an array of values.